# React useState setter function not updating in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project in react where I just don't understand why `selectedRow` is always null. Why doesn't the `setSelectedRow` function set it inside of the `onClick` callback? I tried logging it to the console and it always returns undefined. I've tried using `let myVar` as well and it does the same thing. I feel like there's some secret sauce here I'm missing. Anyone else have an idea?

I expect `selectedRow` to be undefined on the first click, but on subsequent clicks it should be populated. Another conundrum is the fact that `setSelectedGameData` appears to be working just fine. I've validated that `event.currentTarget` is a defined html component

```
import React, {MouseEvent, useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {scheduleGridColumnDefs, sequenceGenerate} from "./util";
import ScheduleGridBodyRowCol from "./ScheduleGridBodyRowCol";


function ScheduleGridBodyRow(
  props: {
    game: any,
    setSelectedGameData: Function,
    selectedGameData: any,
    weekData: any[]
  }
) {
  const {game, setSelectedGameData, selectedGameData, weekData} = props;
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState<any>();
  const onClick = useCallback((event: MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    const gameId = Number(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-game-id'));
    console.log(selectedRow);
    if (selectedRow) {
      selectedRow.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#212529');
    } else {
      setSelectedRow(event.currentTarget);
      console.log(event.currentTarget);
      event.currentTarget.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#4d5154');
      const newlySelectedGameData = weekData.filter((game: any) => game.id === gameId)[0];
      setSelectedGameData(newlySelectedGameData);
    }
  }, [selectedRow, setSelectedGameData, weekData, setSelectedRow]);
  return (
    <tr id={game.id} data-game-id={game.id} onClick={onClick}>
      {scheduleGridColumnDefs.map((columnDef: any) => (
        <ScheduleGridBodyRowCol key={sequenceGenerate()} game={game} columnDef={columnDef}/>
        )
      )}
    </tr>
  );
}

export default React.memo(ScheduleGridBodyRow);
```

The specific line I can't wrap my head around is why this line isn't working as I'd expect it to set the selected row variable:

```
setSelectedRow(event.currentTarget);
```

Can any gracious person help out?

Edit:
I tried the solution from and I'm seeing the same issue when my code looks like:

```
function ScheduleGridBodyRow(
  props: {
    game: any,
    setSelectedGameData: Function,
    selectedGameData: any,
    weekData: any[]
  }
) {
  const {game, setSelectedGameData, selectedGameData, weekData} = props;
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState<any>();
  const onClick = useCallback((event: MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
    const gameId = Number(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-game-id'));
    setSelectedRow((prevSelectedRow: any) => {
      console.log(prevSelectedRow);
      if (prevSelectedRow) {
        prevSelectedRow.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#212529');
        return null;
      } else {
        event.currentTarget.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#4d5154');
        return event.currentTarget;
      }
    });
      const newlySelectedGameData = weekData.filter((game: any) => game.id === gameId)[0];
      setSelectedGameData(newlySelectedGameData);
    }, [setSelectedGameData, weekData, setSelectedRow]);
  return (
    <tr id={game.id} data-game-id={game.id} onClick={onClick}>
      {scheduleGridColumnDefs.map((columnDef: any) => (
        <ScheduleGridBodyRowCol key={sequenceGenerate()} game={game} columnDef={columnDef}/>
        )
      )}
    </tr>
  );
}
```

in this case everytime I log `prevSelectedRow` it's always undefined.

EDIT:
I'm onto it. There's a circurlar reference with reading and updating `selectedRow` in the same function

Comment: Where are you logging it?

Comment: @Bergi Edited for clarification. I'm logging it at the start of the callback

Comment: Then it should be defined on the second click - unless there is something in the rest of your code that causes the entire row to be remounted

Comment: So I am going crazy. What could cause the entire row to be `remounted`?. I don't even know what that would mean

Comment: @GDub Is it possible to create a [mre] that shows us your issue? Either using [code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) or something like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? Creating a small reproducible example also can help with spotting the issue yourself.

Comment: @GDub See https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state. I have a feeling you are accidentally [resetting state by (ab)using a `key`](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key), at least the `key={sequenceGenerate()}` you are using for the cells inside your row looks wrong. What does `sequenceGenerate()` do and why are you using it?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! Fixing that did allow me to see the circular issue in the console. I shouldn't be reading and setting `selectedRow` in the same function. I need to figure out how I'm going to do that.

Comment: @GDub No that part seems fine - especially if you *expect* `selectedRow` to have the value set in the previous click. Unless your actual code is different than what you've shown.

Comment: Btw I'd get rid of the `useCallback`, it seems unnecessary and appears to cause some confusion (unrelated to the actual issue which is still unclear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at hand was the entire component, was getting re-rendered every time I did a click.

Note:

```
function ScheduleGridBodyRow(
  props: {
    game: any,
    setSelectedGameData: Function,
    selectedGameData: any,
    weekData: any[]
  }
)
```

On everytime we `setSelectedGameData` the entire component updates and forgets the history

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is due to how **React** handles state updates. When you call `setSelectedRow`, it schedules an update to the `selectedRow` state variable, but it doesn't immediately update it. This is why you're seeing `undefined` when you log `selectedRow` immediately after calling `setSelectedRow`.

In your `onClick` function, you're trying to access the `style` property of `selectedRow`, which is `undefined` at the time of the first click. This is why you're not seeing the expected behavior.

For this, you could use a ref to store the selected row instead of using state. A ref provides a way to access DOM nodes or react elements directly, and it persists for the full lifetime of the component.

Example;

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';

function ScheduleGridBodyRow(
 props: {
   game: any,
   setSelectedGameData: Function,
   selectedGameData: any,
   weekData: any[]
 }
) {
 const {game, setSelectedGameData, selectedGameData, weekData} = props;
 const selectedRowRef = useRef<HTMLTableRowElement>(null);

 const onClick = useCallback((event: MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement>) => {
   const gameId = Number(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-game-id'));
   if (selectedRowRef.current) {
     selectedRowRef.current.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#212529');
   }
   selectedRowRef.current = event.currentTarget;
   selectedRowRef.current.style.setProperty('--bs-table-bg', '#4d5154');
   const newlySelectedGameData = weekData.filter((game: any) => game.id === gameId)[0];
   setSelectedGameData(newlySelectedGameData);
 }, [setSelectedGameData, weekData]);

 return (
   <tr id={game.id} data-game-id={game.id} onClick={onClick}>
     {scheduleGridColumnDefs.map((columnDef: any) => (
       <ScheduleGridBodyRowCol key={sequenceGenerate()} game={game} columnDef={columnDef}/>
       )
     )}
   </tr>
 );
}

export default React.memo(ScheduleGridBodyRow);
```

In the above code, `selectedRowRef` is a ref that stores the currently selected row. When a row is clicked, the `onClick` function checks if `selectedRowRef.current` is defined, and if it is, it changes the background color of the previously selected row. Then it updates `selectedRowRef.current` to the newly selected row and changes its background color.

This approach avoids the issue of trying to update and access the state variable at the same time, which was causing the problem in your original code.

Comment: "*This is why you're seeing `undefined` when you log `selectedRow` immediately after calling `setSelectedRow`.*" - OP does not do that. And in fact they do expect it to be undefined in the first call, please re-read the question (and notice the `if (selectedRow)`).